# Tips for golfing in LOLCODE

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in LOLCODE? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to LOLCODE. (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: I had thought about posting this myself. It's actually not impossible to golf in LOLCODE.

Comment: Somewhat embarassingly, my second and third highest upvoted answers are in LOLCODE. So I will take this opportunity to share everything I know.

Answer (score 8):

Define variables using the syntax `variable R value` rather than `I HAS A variable ITZ value`.

If you want to set a variable `n` equal to 1,

```
n R 1
```

is only 5 bytes, whereas

```
I HAS A n ITZ 1
```

is 15 bytes.

Comment: But then you lose the whole point of LOLCODE!

Comment: @Optimizer: To be fair, when is there ever a point to LOLCODE?

Comment: The point of LOLCODE is for the lols, of course.

Comment: @ace: Okay, you got me there.

Comment: lol​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Wait, can't you only do that if the var is already defined?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I think it depends on which interpreter you're using.

Comment: Using the lolcode.org language spec, it implies that `<var> R <value>` is only to change the value of a variable, similar to Javascript's `var foo=bar` vs `foo=bar`

Comment: @OldBunny2800 On this site we define languages by their implementations rather than their specifications. The `R` initialization and assignment works in LOLCoffee, the one available on http://repl.it.

Comment: `AWSUM THX`! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases it's shorter to read variable values from STDIN rather than defining a function. However, note that `GIMMEH`, which reads input from STDIN, always reads a `YARN` (i.e. string). But you can take advantage of LOLCODE's dynamic typing and add 0 to convert to a `NUMBR`.

For example,

```
GIMMEH n
n R SUM OF n AN 0    
... (operations on n)
```

Defining `n` is 26 bytes, including newlines. Compare this to a user-defined function:

```
HOW DUZ I f YR n
    ... (operations on n)
IF U SAY SO
```

This requires 28 bytes.

Note that you could also multiply by 1 to convert to a `NUMBR`, but that requires 4 more bytes than the sum:

```
GIMMEH n
n R PRODUKT OF n AN 1
```

Comment: But `n IS NOW A NUMBR` is one byte shorter than `n R SUM OF n AN 0`

Comment: @LeakyNun Which implementation has that? I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 3):

In many LOLCODE implementations, such as the one on [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/LOLCODE), `HAI` and `KTHXBYE`, which begin and end programs respectively, are unnecessary. In implementations in which they are necessary, the version number after `HAI` isn't necessary (e.g. `HAI 1.2`).

Similarly, the `STDIO` library is typically loaded by default, so `CAN HAS STDIO?` is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

When printing the value of a variable to STDOUT, consider the following:

```
VISIBLE variable
```

is much shorter than

```
VISIBLE ":{variable}"
```

Also, whenever a trailing newline is acceptable,

```
VISIBLE variable
```

which includes a trailing newline by default, is shorter than

```
VISIBLE variable!
```

which suppresses the newline.

Answer (score 2):

Many operators have optional `AN`s in between them, as defined in the [spec](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec). For example:

```
SMOOSH "hello" AN ", world" MKAY
```

can be turned into this:

```
SMOOSH "hello" ", world" MKAY
```

Other operators that support this include `BOTH`, `EITHER`, `WON`, `ALL`, `ANY`, `BOTH SAEM`, and `DIFFRINT`. For some reason, the numerical operators don't allow you to remove the `AN`, though.

The spec also says, specifically for `SMOOSH`, [that](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md#concatenation):

> The line ending may safely implicitly close the `SMOOSH` operator without needing an `MKAY`.

Meaning this code should also be valid:

```
SMOOSH "hello" ", world"
```

However, the current version of lci doesn't seem to accept this behaviour :(

Answer (score 1):

LOLCODE (surprisingly) doesn't actually need indentation, meaning you can turn this:

```
HOW IZ I FIB YR N
    I HAS A SML ITZ SMALLR OF N AN 1
    BOTH SAEM N AN SML
    O RLY?
        YA RLY
            FOUND YR 1
        NO WAI
            I HAS A FIRST ITZ I IZ FIB YR DIFF OF N AN 1 MKAY
            I HAS A SECOND ITZ I IZ FIB YR DIFF OF N AN 2 MKAY
            FOUND YR SUM OF FIRST AN SECOND
    OIC
IF U SAY SO
```

Into this:

```
HOW IZ I FIB YR N
I HAS A SML ITZ SMALLR OF N AN 1
BOTH SAEM N AN SML
O RLY?
YA RLY
FOUND YR 1
NO WAI
I HAS A FIRST ITZ I IZ FIB YR DIFF OF N AN 1 MKAY
I HAS A SECOND ITZ I IZ FIB YR DIFF OF N AN 2 MKAY
FOUND YR SUM OF FIRST AN SECOND
OIC
IF U SAY SO
```